# Check if cookie exists for age verification

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie, zurb-reveal

Trying to check if cookie exists. If it does not, fire a foundation reveal modal. On click of a button on the modal set a new cookie, so that the next time the page is loaded the modal is not loaded.

I managed to set the cookie, however my check does not seem to work, as my modal box is appearing even when the cookie is on my browser history.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if ($.cookie('ageVerification') == undefined || $.cookie('ageVerification') == null || $.cookie('ageVerification') != 'Verification that user is over the legal drinking age in your country') {

        // Reveal modal
        $("#myModal").reveal();

        // Set Cookie on click 
        var ageVerification = document.getElementById('ageVerification');

        ageVerification.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            $.cookie('ageVerification', 'Verification that user is over the legal drinking age in there country', {
                expires: 10, //expires in 10 days

                path: '/', //The value of the path attribute of the cookie 
                //(default: path of page that created the cookie).

                domain: 'becketts.knibbshost.co.uk', //The value of the domain attribute of the cookie
                //(default: domain of page that created the cookie).

                secure: true //If set to true the secure attribute of the cookie
                //will be set and the cookie transmission will
                //require a secure protocol (defaults to false).
            });
            $('#myModal').hideModal()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Your cookie isn't actually being set in the first place http://becketts.knibbshost.co.uk

Comment: Take out your last "or" statement in your cookie check. If it works then there's something missing in the string comparison, perhaps and ending punctuation (.)?

Answer (score -1):

Fixed the extra settings on the set of my cookie, were not working.

answer needs the following scripts to run:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

if ($.cookie('ageVerification') == undefined || $.cookie('ageVerification') == null) {

    // Reveal modal
    $("#myModal").reveal();

    // Set Cookie on click 
    var ageVerificationBtn = document.getElementById('ageVerification');

    ageVerificationBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        $.cookie('ageVerification', 'Verification that user is over the legal drinking age in there country', {
            expires: 10, //expires in 10 days
        });
        $('#myModal').hideModal()
    });
}
```

});